# Post request to mailchimp

Tags: node.js, mailchimp

I want to do a post request to mailchimp api. I don't know how to do it. When I test it on postman it gives error. Also I am not sure how to request the data in the body.

```
const express = require('express');
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-v3');
const MailChimpConfig = require('./.env');

const app = express();
const mailchimp = new Mailchimp(MailChimpConfig.MAILCHIMP_API_KEY);

app.get('/api/memberList',(req, res) => {
  mailchimp.get(`/lists/${MailChimpConfig.MAILING_LIST_ID}/members`)
  .then(function(results){
    res.send(results);
  }).catch(function(err){
    res.send(err);
  });
});
app.post('/api/create',(req, res) => {
    mailchimp.post(`/lists/${MailChimpConfig.MAILING_LIST_ID}/members`, {
        email_address: email,
        status: 'subscribed',
        merge_fields: {
            'FNAME': firstName,
            'LNAME': lastName,
        }
    })
    .then(function(results){
        res.send(results);
    }
    ).catch(function (err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```

When I test it on postman I should create a new member with email, first name and last name.

Comment: show you postman error

Comment: email is not defined

Answer (score -1):

Use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) module to send request

```
app.post('/api/create',(req, res) => {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        url: `${MailChimpConfig.URL}/lists/${MailChimpConfig.MAILING_LIST_ID}/members`,
        headers: {
            Authorization: `apiKey ${MailChimpConfig.apiKey}`
        },
        body: {
            email_address: email,
            status: 'subscribed',
            merge_fields: {
                'FNAME': firstName,
                'LNAME': lastName,
            }
        }
    })
    .then(function(results){
            res.send(results);
        }
    ).catch(function (err) {
        res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: my get request to mailchimp works fine. I have added the get request code

Comment: I don't have a URL in my Mailchimpconfig. so how does it fetch the url?